# how to keep separator out of nave pill

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, nav-pills

[image]

This is created using following code -

```
<div class="container" style="padding-top: 5px;width:95%">
    <ul class="nav nav-pills">
        <li><a href="#"><b>Dashboard</b><span class="divider" style="padding-left:20px;">|</span></a></li> 
        <li class="active"><a href="#"><b>Current Order</b> <span class="divider" style="padding-left:20px;">|</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><b>Price Book</b><span class="divider" style="padding-left:20px;">|</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><b>View History</b></a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

here the separator is included in the active tab area.How to keep it away from text with equal diatance from links?

Comment: Its really a good thinking ! great flute

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

## [LIVE_DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/jq8hdzy5/4/)

CSS:

```
  .div {
            padding:10px 15px 10px 15px;
        }
```

HTML

```
  <div class="container" style="padding-top: 5px;width:95%">
                <ul class="nav nav-pills">
                    <li><a href="#"><b>Dashboard</b></a></li> 
                    <li class="div"><span class="divider">|</span></li>
                    <li><a href="#"><b>Current Order</b> </a></li>
                    <li class="div"><span class="divider">|</span></li>
                    <li><a href="#"><b>Price Book</b></a></li>
                    <li class="div"><span class="divider">|</span></li>
                    <li><a href="#"><b>View History</b></a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
```